# Why do these tensor products not commute?

Tags: group-theory, tensor-products

I'm asked to find show if the set of pauli matrices in three orthogonal spaces form algebra, namely

$\sigma_a$ and  $\tau_a$ and $\eta_a $ and  $\sigma_a \tau_b  \eta_c$

When I try to find tensor products between the for example, the pauli matrices in the first space, $\sigma_a \otimes \mathbf{i}\otimes \mathbf{i}$, and $\sigma_a \otimes \tau_b \otimes \eta_c$, I find that they commute in my calculations, but they shouldn't be according to Mathematica and the question. Can someone help me find the tensor product relationship?

Comment: Assuming that **i** denotes the identity matrix, the two specific  matrices you mentioned do commute.